# Woocommerce removing applied coupon code not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove all applied coupon codes when a specific category isn't in cart, but I can't seem to get it working. Does anybody know why it doesn't work? The coupon just remains in cart and also discount is still applied, which should all be removed when the specific category isn't in cart.

Am I missing something obvious?

I've updated it with $woocommerce.

Thanks in advance!

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'check_category_in_cart');
function check_category_in_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cat_in_cart = false;
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_term( 'tickets', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $cat_in_cart = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$cat_in_cart) {
        $applied_coupons = $woocommerce->cart->get_applied_coupons();
        if (count($applied_coupons) > 0) {
            $woocommerce->cart->remove_coupons();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if this contributes to solution but you forgot parenthesis after `get_applied_coupons`. This should be `get_applied_coupons()`

Comment: Also don't use `WC()->` but declare `$woocommerce` globally once like this: `global $woocommerce` then use it like this `$woocommerce->cart->get_cart()`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've updated it now, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Which hook are you using? Can you add the part where you add the action or filter?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the hook.